# coalescing in linq join for equals

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to join two objects in linq as below:

```
var clients = from cts in ctList
              join pc in personList on ct.name equals pc.name
              select new 
              {
                ip = pc.Ip,
                clts = cts
              };
```

**Actual Result:**
I am getting clients with no result when personList is null.

**Expected:**
When personList is null, we are still supposed to receive the clients result but assigning ip to be '-'
when no result in personList.

I want to achieve like below but it is not working:

```
join pc in personList on ct.name equals pc?.name ?? ct.name
```

I would really appreciate for the help. Thank you!

Comment: you should use left join to achieve this

Comment: @ sajid, I think it is a left join. Isn't it?

Comment: no, i will build query for that, but you can check : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using left join, the query will be :

```
var clients = from cts in ctList
              join pc in personList on cts.name equals pc.name into lefedResults
              from lefedResult in lefedResults.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new 
              {
                ip = lefedResult?.Ip ?? "-",
                clts = cts
              };
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```
var clients = from cts in ctList
    from pc in personList.Where(x => x.name == cts.name).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        ip = pc?.Ip ?? "-",
        clts = cts
    };
```

**Solution 2:**

```
var clients = from cts in ctList
              select new
              {
                  ip = personList.Where(x => x.name == cts.name).Select(x => x.Ip).FirstOrDefault() ?? "-",
                  clts = cts
              };
```

**Solution 3:**

```
var clients = ctList.Select(cts => new
{
    clts = cts,
    ip = personList.Where(x => x.name == cts.name).Select(x => x.Ip).DefaultIfEmpty("-").First()
});
```

Comment: Why not use the standard left join idiom?

Comment: Isn't that in solution 1, we should have join in between from tables?

Comment: @NetMage there are many ways to write the queries. This question is about linq to object, so there are many ways to write it. Check the updated answer, another variant.

Comment: @CodeVenture No, Solution one is an inner join, you needed a left join.

Comment: I don't think it is best to mix lambda/fluent method syntax and query syntax in one expression when it can be avoided, even when using LINQ to Objects. It adds unnecessary confusion for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Find an example below with minor changes to increase robustness assuming the input list may not be sanitized:

More details available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins.

**--- Output (Console Application) ---**

```
John -> 10.0.0.5
Sally -> 10.0.0.7
Sally -> 10.0.0.9
Sally -> -
<Unknown User> -> 10.1.1.100
<Unknown User> -> -
<Unknown User> -> -
```

**--- Classes ---**

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Client
{
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }

    public string Ip { get; set; }
}
```

**--- LINQ Query ---**

```
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>{
            new Person { Name = "John" },
            new Person { Name = "Mary" },
            new Person { Name = "Sally" },
            new Person { Name = null },
            null
        };

        List<Client> machines = new List<Client>{
            new Client { OwnerName = "John", Ip = "10.0.0.5" },
            new Client { OwnerName = "Sally", Ip = "10.0.0.7" },
            new Client { OwnerName = "Sally", Ip = "10.0.0.9" },
            new Client { OwnerName = "Sally", Ip = null }, // Sally -> -
            new Client { OwnerName = null, Ip = "10.1.1.100" }, // <Unknown User> -> 10.1.1.100
            new Client { OwnerName = null, Ip = null }, // <Unknown User> -> -
            null // <Unknown User> -> -
        };

        if (people != null && machines != null)
        {
            var query = from machine in machines
                        join person in people on machine?.OwnerName equals person?.Name into gj
                        select new { Name = machine?.OwnerName?? "<Unknown User>", Ip = machine?.Ip ?? "-" };

            foreach (var result in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{result.Name} -> {result.Ip}");
            }
        }
```